# Make some replacements on a bunch of files depending the number of columns per line

Tags: sed, awk

I'm having a problem dealing with some files. I need to perform a column count for every line in a file and depending the number of columns i need to add severals ',' in in the end of each line. All lines should have 36 columns separated by ','

This line solves my problem, but how do I run it in a folder with several files in a automated way?

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS = "," } ; 
{if (NF == 32) { print $0",,,," } else if (NF==31) { print $0",,,,," }
}' <SOURCE_FILE> > <DESTINATION_FILE>
```

Thank you for all your support
R&P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on your OS, which you haven't told us. On UNIX and assuming you want to modify each original file, it'd be:

```
for file in *
do
    awk '...' "$file" > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

Also, in general to get all records in a file to have the same number of fields you can do this without needing to specify what that number of fields is (though you can if appropriate):

```
$ cat tst.awk        
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[ARGC-1] }
NR==FNR { nf = (NF > nf ? NF : nf); next }
{
    tail = sprintf("%*s",nf-NF,"")
    gsub(/ /,OFS,tail)
    print $0 tail
}
$ 
$ cat file           
a,b,c
a,b
a,b,c,d,e
$ 
$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,b,c,,
a,b,,,
a,b,c,d,e
$ 
$ awk -v nf=10 -f tst.awk file
a,b,c,,,,,,,
a,b,,,,,,,,
a,b,c,d,e,,,,,
```

Comment: Thank You Ed Morton. Your first tip did the job for me. All my activities are performed on RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

if this is only a single folder without subfolders, use:

```sh
for oldfile in /path/to/files/*
do
   newfile="${oldfile}.new"
   awk '...' "${oldfile}" > "${newfile}"
done
```

if you also want to include subdirectories recursively, it's probably easiest to put the awk+redirection into a small shell-script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
oldfile=$1
newfile="${oldfile}.new"
awk '...' "${oldfile}" > "${newfile}"
```

and then run this script (let's calls it `runawk.sh`) via find:

```
find /path/to/files/ -type f -not -name "*.new" -exec runawk.sh \{\} \;
```

Comment: Just be careful in case you have files named "foo" and "foo.new" already existing in your directory in which case you'll mistakenly overwrite "foo.new".

Comment: thank you Glenn Jackman! In my next version of the script I will need to search for specific files in several directories, so your tip will help me as well. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

It's a short one-liner with Perl:

```
perl -i.bak -F, -alpe '$_ .= "," x (36-@F)' *
```